# Using jquery to change Header Text on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, click

I'm currently attempting to get my Javascript code to mesh with HTML written by someone else. The goal is to get the header to change by using jquery by typing it into a text input box and then clicking on a button.

Not exactly sure why it isn't working. In my mind it seems as if it should be functioning properly. If someone could help find a correct solution and explain to me why mine isn't working it would be much appreciated.

```
(HTML shortened)
<tr> <td colspan=2 align=right> Title:<input type=text id=newTitle value="Picture Title"> </td> <td> <button id=genTitle>Change Title</button> </td> </tr>

<h2 id=artTitle align=center>Picture Title</h2>

(javascript)
var newTitle = $('#newTitle').val();
$( "#genTitle" ).click(function() {
    $( "#artTitle" ).text(newTitle)
                                  })
```

Comment: Move `var newTitle = $('#newTitle').val();` inside the click handler to get the latest value from the textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this. (I hope you have the correct html, make sure to have all the quotes and doublequotes wrapped around every attribute properly.)

```
// Set a event on button click
$("#genTitle").click(function(){

    // Fetch Input Value
    var val = $("#newTitle").val();

    // Set the value fetched as the html of header
    $("#artTitle").html(val);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The value must be extracted inside the `click`.

So the Javascript code becomes:

```
$( "#genTitle" ).click(function() {
    var newTitle = $('#newTitle').val();
    $( "#artTitle" ).text(newTitle)
})
```

[See the fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/85egb561/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example for you.

```js
$( "#genTitle" ).click(function() {
    var newTitle = $('#newTitle').val();
    $( "#artTitle" ).text(newTitle)
                                  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr> 
    <td colspan=2 align=right> Title: <input type=text id="newTitle" value="Picture Title">     </td>     
    <td> <button id="genTitle">Change Title</button> </td> 
</tr>

<h2 id="artTitle" align="center">Picture Title</h2>
```